# Difference between Java array assignments

Tags: java

I have been programming in Java for quite some time and this question popped up suddenly in my head.

What is the difference between writing:

```
int[] a = new int[SIZE];
int a[] = new int[SIZE];
```

Both of them seem to work fine on my machine.

Comment: both are same , just a preference based but this `int[]` makes more sense at first look

Comment: I code like int[] a in java and int a[] in C.

Comment: agree with @PavneetSingh, I guess reading left to right i would easily notice that the variable after `[]` is referencing an array type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, it's the same. But if you declare more than one variable in the same line, then there is a difference.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Particularly, these declarations:

```
short     s,         // scalar short
          aas[][];   // array of array of short
Object[]  ao,        // array of Object
          otherAo;   // array of Object
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for.